# How can I find how many of my GitHub pull requests have been accepted?

Tags: git, github, github-api, pull-request

Is there a way to find out the acceptance rate of one's GitHub PR's, probably using the API?

While at that, it would be interesting to find out how many of the issues I reported have been closed vs. are still open, across all repos.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to use a single request to get total number of issues, PR with count per state (`CLOSED`, `OPENED` or `MERGED`) :

```graphql
{
  user(login: "bertrandmartel") {
    totalPR: pullRequests {
      totalCount
    }
    openedPR: pullRequests(states: OPEN) {
      totalCount
    }
    closedPR: pullRequests(states: CLOSED) {
      totalCount
    }
    mergedPR: pullRequests(states: MERGED) {
      totalCount
    }
    totalIssues: issues {
      totalCount
    }
    openedIssues: issues(states: OPEN) {
      totalCount
    }
    closedIssues: issues(states: CLOSED) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20user(login%3A%20%22bertrandmartel%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20totalPR%3A%20pullRequests%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20openedPR%3A%20pullRequests(states%3A%20OPEN)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20closedPR%3A%20pullRequests(states%3A%20CLOSED)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20mergedPR%3A%20pullRequests(states%3A%20MERGED)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20totalIssues%3A%20issues%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20openedIssues%3A%20issues(states%3A%20OPEN)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20closedIssues%3A%20issues(states%3A%20CLOSED)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

which gives you a result like the following :

```json
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "totalPR": {
        "totalCount": 17
      },
      "openedPR": {
        "totalCount": 4
      },
      "closedPR": {
        "totalCount": 1
      },
      "mergedPR": {
        "totalCount": 12
      },
      "totalIssues": {
        "totalCount": 80
      },
      "openedIssues": {
        "totalCount": 7
      },
      "closedIssues": {
        "totalCount": 73
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## 2023 GitHub New Design Update

With the recent implementation of the new GitHub UI, locating all the Pull Requests assigned to you has become effortless. Simply navigate to your profile and utilize the designated button to access them.

[image]

##### For your convenience, you can easily replace `YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME` with your GitHub username when using the following link:

`https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Apr+archived%3Afalse+author%3AYOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME`

Comment: You can use https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Apr+archived%3Afalse+author%3A%40me to view your own PRs without needing to replace your own username in the link.

Comment: This should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a way to get that information directly. That leaves you with the [GitHub Issues Events API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/).
With that, you can list all the events of a repo:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/events
https://api.github.com/repos/user/reponame/issues/events
```

And filter on a user and an event (looking for `"merged": true`)

Answer (score 2):

Certainly there is an indirect way to know your all accepted PR requests and that is **GitHub resume**. Yes, **GitHub resume** is something which generates resume of users on the basis of their GitHub activity.

So, go and star the project https://github.com/resume/resume.github.com and then visit http://resume.github.io. There you will see list of your all accepted PR requests.

**Note**: You need to star the project first, they don't allow to generate the resume otherwise.

Comment: I think it's showing a list of popular repositories only (not list of PRs). By the way it's "star" the project (not "start")

Answer (score 2):

Login your GitHub

Then visit - https://github.com/pulls

Click on the closed section.

You will see all the past PRs.

In case you want to check how many of them are merged and how many are closed, simply use the Crtl+F or Find option in your browser and then type merged/closed according to your requirement.